# Pagination in boto3 ec2 describe instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am having an issue with pagination in boto3 & not getting all instances in the aws account.

Only getting 50% of the instances with below (around 2000 where as there are 4000)

Below is my code

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

paginator = ec2.get_paginator('describe_instances')
response = paginator.paginate().build_full_result()

ec2_instance = response['Reservations']


for instance in ec2_instance:
    print(instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId'])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response from `describe_instances()` is:

```
{
    'Reservations': [
        {
            'Groups': [
                {
                    'GroupName': 'string',
                    'GroupId': 'string'
                },
            ],
            'Instances': [
                {
                    'AmiLaunchIndex': 123,
 ...
```

Notice that the response is:

- A dictionary
- Where `Reservations` is a **list** containing:

  - `Instances`, which is a **list**

Therefore, the code really needs to loop through all Reservations and instances.

At the moment, your code is looping through the Reservations (incorrectly calling them instances), and is then only retrieving the first (`[0]`) instance from that Reservation.

You'll probably want some code like this:

```py
for reservation in response['Reservations']:
  for instance in reservation['Instances']:
    print(instance['InstanceId'])
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use `resource` not `client` then you don't need to worry about pagination.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

response = ec2.instances.all()
for item in response:
    print(item.id)
```

The code will give you all results.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of calling build_full_result(), you could do this:

```
from boto3 import client

for page in client('ec2').get_paginator('describe_instances').paginate():
    for res in page['Reservations']:
        for inst in res['Instances']:
            print( inst['InstanceId'])
```

Calling build_full_result() could defeat the purpose of pagination, namely to manage memory.