# Clean Boto3 Pagination

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pagination, boto3

I am trying to find a very nice python idiom to use aws boto3 paginators in the most "pythonic" way. Below is the best I have been able to come up with and I'm still not happy with it. Any ideas on how to make pagination simpler, possibly not using `while True:`?

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('acm', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

paginator = client.get_paginator('list_certificates')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate()

while True:
    for certificates in response_iterator:
        for certificate in certificates['CertificateSummaryList']:
            print(certificate)

    if response_iterator.resume_token:
        response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
            PaginationConfig={
                'StartingToken': response_iterator.resume_token
            })
    else:
        break
```

Comment: The whole point of paginators is that you don't need to deal with continuation tokens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Woudn't the following form work?:

```
client = boto3.client('acm', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

paginator = client.get_paginator('list_certificates')

for page in paginator.paginate():
    print(page)
```

Comment: that does work from what I can see, could you explain why I don't need to pass `StartingToken` with this approach?

Comment: @JustinS When you use `paginator.paginate()`, boto3 will take care of passing `StartingToken` around in the backend. This way you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: ok cool, thanks for the info and answer @Marcin

Comment: @JustinS No problem. Glad it helped:-)

Comment: Gotta say, this is not obvious from the Boto3 docs - thank you! :)

Comment: @Marcin, I was testing with PaginationConfig, and it was not listing all resources but when removed PaginationConfig it was listing all resources. I am trying to undo my down vote, but it's locked. Sorry for downvote.

Answer (score 4):

It’s not really documented but you can do something like this with paginators

```py
client = boto3.client('acm')
results = (
    client.get_paginator('list_certificates')
    .paginate()
    .build_full_result()
)
print(results)
```

> edit

a similar approach for `ec2` which has one of the more annoying response structures:

```py
import jmespath

client = boto3.client('ec2')
results = (
   client.get_paginator('describe_instances')
   .paginate()
   .build_full_result()
)

# jmespath could be replaced with some nested for loops if you prefer, but I find this "cleaner" and easier to read.

instances = jmespath.search('Reservations[].Instances[]')

for i in instances:
  print(i['InstanceId'])
```

You can generate an example output response which is super handy for most, if not all, the services which has probably saved me *days* in trying to figure.

Unfortunately, [I think there's a bug in the aws-cli skeleton output for `acm list-certificates`](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/6728)

but the equivalent for `ec2.describe_instances` just for fun.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --generate-cli-skeleton output
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Groups": [
                {
                    "GroupName": "GroupName",
                    "GroupId": "GroupId"
                }
            ],
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
                    "ImageId": "ImageId",
                    "InstanceId": "InstanceId",
                    "InstanceType": "InstanceType",
                    "KernelId": "KernelId",
                    "KeyName": "KeyName",
                    "LaunchTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "Monitoring": {
                        "State": "State"
                    },
  ...
```

Comment: I've used this method without problems for several projects. I don't understand why it isn't documented and made a 'first-class' solution. What's wrong with this nice and lazy approach? :)

Comment: it doesn't work any more, I got empty result.

Comment: How do I iterate over the results with an ec2 client? I tried various stuff that usually work like `for instance in results: print(instance['Reservations'][0])` but I keep getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers`, which doesn't appear when using the 'normal' methods.

Comment: @Daniel sorry just saw this!  edited my answer with some more context: I think you're hitting that error because `results` is a dictionary with only a _single_ `Reservations` key.  This answer has a really good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900090/4526019